# SEO: Making data and URLs retrieved from database, crawlable and indexable

Tags: asp.net, seo, dynamic-url

I have an asp.net .aspx page(say fruits.aspx page) which lists all the fruits(apple, banana, mango etc) with a thumbnail, title and link which leads to each fruit's respective detail page. Now all this data is being retrieved from an XML with the help of backhand code with help of an XSLT and user-control.

Now since the data and URLs of each fruit's detail page are not there statically on this page, it will not be crawled and indexed as per my knowledge.

Is there a workaround that I can do to make each fruit's detail page crawled and indexed.

If I had the dynamic URLs only with something like "?var=value", I could solve it with static/dynamic conversion using URL re-write. But here the URL itself is not there but is generated from code behind.

Comment: It does not matter if the URLs are put there from a code behind (dynamically) or are hard-coded in the HTML. The search engine simply sees the resulting HTML containing the URL. It does not know or care how it was generated.

Comment: Can you please verify this again. What you mean to say is that search engines see the page as it appears in browser after all data is loaded and not the raw page as it appears in directory of my application which contains no data but the place holders which are filled from code behind??

Comment: Correct. Search engines cannot see your ASPX file as it sits on your server - they only see the resulting, generated HTML. The same you would see if you did a "view source" from your web browser.

Comment: Thanks sir! That answer's my problem.. Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search engines will not see the `aspx` file as it sits on your server; Instead, they see the same thing your web browser does: the resulting HTML output.

This means that the parameters you speak of *will* be seen and indexed properly by search engines.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it then. Each page you want indexed must have a unique URL. When you generate the page, just generate a unique URL. Take your query parameters and paste them on the end of your script name.

For example say that fruits.aspx is called with ?fruit=banana as a query parameter. Your best option is to generate a page with a unique static URL for example make the link to the banana page look like /fruits.aspx/fruit/banana.

Even better would be to rewrite it to remove the .aspx. Then the site looks like all static content, which is even better for indexing. If a URL looks like it is backed by a databasem the search engine is less likely to index everything.

Comment: "if a URL looks like it is backed by a database the search engine is less likely to index everything", I would sure like to see some evidence of that, as I do not believe that to be true at all.

Comment: It is easy to make a database which has an infinite number of pages. Search engines will index a site less deeply if they detect they are crawling a huge number of parameters. Take an online store for example where I can organize products by color, size and brand using query parameters. If the engine sees a bunch of query parameters that all lead to similar content it indexes less deeply. If the pages are organized in static looking dirs it makes the assumption that this is all real static content, and will set a higher threshold for when it stops indexing.

Comment: That is not the same thing that the answer above says, and to the extent that is true, the *exact* same thing would happen if it seemed a site had a near-infinite number of 'directories'.

Comment: It will happen later with static URLs. On Google URLs with query parameters go through query parameter normalization. Where they try to figure out which parameters matter to the content, and which parameters can be reordered and produce the same content. This is more work for Google and less time spent crawling your site. Bing is less sophisticated in query parameter handling. Also URLs without query parameters have a higher CTR.

Comment: 1) I *highly* doubt the OP here has anywhere near enough parameter values to make any difference at all. 2) See the comments to the question; this isn't actually what he's talking about, anyway. He was thinking that search engines see the 'raw' ASPX, rather than the generated HTML.

Comment: Additionally, you are making a common error: "Static URLs" is essentially a meaningless term. Routing/Rewriting mean you can't assume anything about a site from its URL scheme. Search engines know this... they aren't in the Dark Ages, thinking all websites are "static". They wouldn't be very useful if they did.

Comment: You have a point here Andrew.. But even I have seen all the articles about SEO saying that a url like "mydomain.com/details/index/type/'bangles'/product-id/bang101/" is more SE Optimized than a url like "mydomain.com/details/?type='bangles'&product-id=bang101"